# How to remove "chrome is being controlled by automated test software" selenium javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Is there anyway to remove the "chrome is being controlled by automated test software" notification in selenium JavaScript. Already tried disable info-bar but turns out chrome patched that couple years back.

Answer (score 4):

```
var options = new chrome.Options();

options.excludeSwitches('enable-automation')
```

use chrome options.excludeSwitches, this will remove the automation flag that causing that notification

Answer (score 1):

For C# :

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddExcludedArgument("enable-automation");
```

Comment: This also works for `EdgeOptions`.

Answer (score 0):

In Python,

```
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions
options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
```